# Re-sorting a CActiveDataProvider

Tags: php, sorting, yii

I am looking for a way in Yii to re-sort a CActiveDataProvider.

Currently I am using the the data provider to fetch sorted and paginated data.

I am then looping through it with a foreach loop adjusting data for specific fields, and now I need to re-sort it based upon the new adjusted data.

I can't sort the data in the model using afterFind because I need to query another DB (MySQL) to work out a calculated value and it doesn't seem to like the switching during the processing.

I don't want to use an CArrayDataProvider because there is no obvious way to paginate the data which comes back unless I put controls into a loop while adjusting the data, however I don't know how much data could come back, say 200 records, but the only adjusting 20 for the display seems counterintuitive.

This all is then pushed to a CGridView widget.

so now I need to readjust on the array below in ascending order for example.

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider( blah );

foreach ( $dataProvider->getData() as $data ) {
 $data->Score += SomeModel::model()->findByPk(1)->NewScore;
}

array(
'Score' => 7
),
array(
'Score' => 6
)

$this->render('blah', array('data' => $dataProvider);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should simply implement a new `CDataProvider` of your own that wraps an existing `CDataProvider`. You will need to override several methods, but for most of them you can simply forward to the wrapped data provider. The code might end up looking something like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(...);
$myProvider = new CustomDataProvider($dataProvider);

// you could make CustomDataProvider work like this:
$myProvider->dataMutator = function(&$row, $key) {
    $row->Score = SomeModel::model()->findByPk(1)->NewScore;
};

$this->render('blah', array('data' => $myProvider);
```

`CustomDataProvider::fetchData` might look like this:

```
protected function fetchData()
{
    $data = $this->wrappedProvider->fetchData();
    array_walk(&$data, $this->dataMutator);
    uasort($data, function($a, $b) { return $a->Score - $b->Score; });
    return $data;
}
```

I 've hardwired the sort here -- this works for prototyping, but to specify the post-processing sort cleanly is not trivial because:

- `CDataProvider` exposes a `sort` property which is ignored. Integrating that property fully would either be non-trivial work (you have to write code that respects multiple sort criteria etc) or change the semantics of `CustomDataProvider.sort` compared to `sort` on its base class. `CDataProvider` is married to `CSort`, so if you wanted to go for the cleanest solution from an OO perspective it would be best to implement `IDataProvider` from scratch.
- It's not intuitive to the user of `CustomDataProvider` how sorting works if a single 'sort`property is used, because`sort` cannot reflect both what the wrapped data provider will do and what the "post-processing" sort will do at the same time; however, both of the above will affect the end result.

I suggest that you get a prototype working and then have a good think about what the object model should be.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I am not sure at which point the data gets resorted or how I should implement it in my custom provider so that it sorts on Score.

Comment: @DamianCrawford: I revised the answer quite a bit, see if it's more useful now. Heads up: now overriding `fetchData` instead of `getData`.

Comment: Hi @Jon, sorry for commenting in different comment. I got stuck in descending order where data is coming in proper descending order when there is no pagination. But, as soon pagination starts , data not coming in proper order. Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560374/descending-order-sorting-not-working-in-pagination-of-cactivedataprovider-yii2